# Cartopy shapefile for Greenland producing Polygon

Tags: shapefile, cartopy

I have been using the cartopy shapefile reader for months to create a mask over Greenland using the following code:

```
from cartopy.mpl.patch import geos_to_path
from shapely.geometry import Point
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader


shpfilename = shpreader.natural_earth(resolution='110m',
                                      category='cultural',
                                      name='admin_0_countries')
reader = shpreader.Reader(shpfilename)
countries = reader.records()
country = next(countries)


gl_multipoly, = [country.geometry for country in countries
                 if country.attributes['NAME'] == 'Greenland']

main_gl_geom = sorted(gl_multipoly.geoms, key=lambda geom: geom.area)
```

However now when I come to the last line 'main_gl_geom' I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Polygon' object has no attribute 'geoms'
```

which I never got before, nor does this appear with a different country such as Canada however in this instance it creates a `Multiploygon` while Greenland is only a 'Polygon' and thus does not have the attribute 'geoms', so I am wondering if there is something else that I need to do to get this working again, or why this might have suddenly stopped working

Comment: FYI  If someone answer your question, and it is good. You can click to accept it and earn some reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

At `110m` resolution, Greenland is not `MultiPolygon`. You can check by running:

```
gl_multipoly.geometryType()
```

and get 'Polygon' as a result.

You may try again using `resolution='50m'`. This time you will get 'MultiPolygon'.